# ItemsSource is empty in constructor of Custom Bound Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I'm having trouble updating Cheesebarons horizontal list view to the new v3 MvvmCross. Everything seems to be working correctly except in the constructor of my "BindableHorizontalListView" control the ItemsSource of the adapter is null. Which is weird because the context shows that the view-model property I am attempting to bind to shows very clearly there are 3 items and the binding seems very straightforward. What am I missing? I hope I've included enough of the code. I've also tried binding it via fluent bindings on the "OnViewModelSet" event with the same result.

Warning presented

```
[MvxBind]  24.87 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on DeviceViewModel
```

AXML

```
 <BindableHorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DevicesList; ItemClick ItemSelected"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/devices_horizontal_list_item" />
```

BindableHorizontalListView control

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Attributes;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;

namespace Project.Droid.Controls
{
    public class BindableHorizontalListView
        : HorizontalListView //Which inherits from AdapterView<BaseAdapter>
    {
        public BindableHorizontalListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
            : this(context, attrs, new MvxAdapter(context))
        {
        }

        public BindableHorizontalListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, MvxAdapter adapter)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
            InitView ();
            var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId (context, attrs);

            adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
            Adapter = adapter;
            SetupItemClickListener();

        }

        public new MvxAdapter Adapter
        {
            get { return base.Adapter as MvxAdapter; }
            set
            {
                var existing = Adapter;
                if (existing == value)
                    return;

                if (existing != null && value != null)
                {
                    value.ItemsSource = existing.ItemsSource;
                    value.ItemTemplateId = existing.ItemTemplateId;
                }

                base.Adapter = value;
            }
        }

        [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return Adapter.ItemsSource; }
            set { Adapter.ItemsSource = value; this.Reset (); }
        }

        public int ItemTemplateId
        {
            get { return Adapter.ItemTemplateId; }
            set { Adapter.ItemTemplateId = value; }
        }

        public new ICommand ItemClick { get; set; }

        private void SetupItemClickListener()
        {
            base.ItemClick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (null == ItemClick)
                    return;
                var item = Adapter.GetItem(args.Position) as Java.Lang.Object;
                if (item == null)
                    return;

                if (item == null)
                    return;

                if (!ItemClick.CanExecute(item))
                    return;

                ItemClick.Execute(item);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
[Activity (Label = "Device", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class DeviceView : MvxActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.device);
    }

}
```

Property on ViewModel

```
private Services.Device[] _devicesList;
public Services.Device[] DevicesList {
    get {
        return _devicesList;
    }
    set {
        _devicesList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => DevicesList);
    }
}
```

If only there was PCL support in XAM STUDIO I would just step in and see how the other controls are doing it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemsSource will always be empty in the constructor - it's a property which is set by binding, and that property can only be set after the constructor has completed.

The message:

```
[MvxBind]  24.87 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on DeviceViewModel
```

contains a bug - fixed in [a recent commit](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/876adf80b21ffea5fb99a1f7fe32bea908bee8dd) - so the message should be more readable in the future.

If the bug hadn't been there, I suspect the message would say that the problem is in `DevicesList` - the binding can't find that property. Is it there? Does it have a `get`? Is it `public`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Added DevicesList code to the question, looks straightforward to me as well, but I'm new to all this MVVM magic

Comment: This is not 'magic' - it's code and normal development. I recommend you try to get it working with a normal list first - just switch over, rebuild all and get it working with a standard list, then switch over to the horizontal list and debug that.

Comment: I've bound plenty of lists and just got done writing the same app on the iPhone. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake somewhere, I'll let the world know when I find it. Thanks for the help. Good to know about the bug, now if only I could build mvvmCross PCL on Xam.Studio myself that would be great.

Comment: I followed your advice and it binds correctly to a listview... turns out the binding isn't the issue at all. Stepping into the controls list filling code now I see the listViewItems are there ... the views just aren't displaying for some reason TBD. Thanks again